# Now Feedback if the connection works

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pykafka

I am trying to create a simple client with pykafka. For this I need SSL certificates. The client runs under RHEL 7 and Python 3.6.x 
It looks like the connection works but I don't get any feedback or data, only a black screen. 
How can I check the connection or get error messages.

```
#!/usr/bin/scl enable rh-python36 -- python3

from pykafka import KafkaClient, SslConfig

config = SslConfig(cafile='key/root_ca.crt',
                   certfile='key/cert.crt',  
                   keyfile='key/key.key',
                   password='xxxx') 

client = KafkaClient(hosts="xxxxxxx:9093", 
                        ssl_config=config)

print("topics", client.topics) 

topic = client.topics['xxxxxx']

consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer(
                    consumer_group="yyyyy",
                    auto_offset_reset=OffsetType.EARLIEST,
                    reset_offset_on_start=False
                    )

for message in consumer:
    if message is not None:
        print (message.offset, message.value)
```

Comment: Are you able to describe the topic with that library? Is data in the topic? Try printing anything after you create the consumer?

Comment: It has data in that topic. It looks like the connection is established but there is something wrong with the certificates. How can I debug it?

Comment: You could edit the question to show how you create the certs